# How to properly deserialise ClientResponse entity to List of POJOs

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I am attempting to deserialise a response entity into a list of POJOs. When I do this directly, using a GenericType like so:

```
private List<UserRole> extractMembersDirectly(final ClientResponse response) {
    return response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<UserRole>>() {});
}
```

I get this exception:

`com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.util.List)`

However, I can deserialise successfully when I use an ObjectMapper directly:

```
private List<UserRole> extractMembersUsingMapper(final ClientResponse response) throws IOException {
    String json = response.getEntity(String.class);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapperFactory().build();
    return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<UserRole>>() {});
}
```

The POJO is just:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonSnakeCase
public class UserRole {
    private UUID id;

    public UserRole(@JsonProperty("id") final UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
}
```

Is there a way to directly deserialise from the entity without first deserialising to String?

Answer (score 0):

you can try having a custom serializer on the class itself

Writing the serializer

```
   public class UserRoleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Item> {
      @Override
      public void serialize(UserRole userRole, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider      provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeStartObject();
    jgen.writeStringField("id", userRole.id);
    jgen.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```

Now registering the serializer to your class

```
     @JsonSerialize(using = UserRoleSerializer.class)
     public class UserRole {
         ...
      }
```

Then Just an idea, not sure if thats what you looking for